# Variable sesión carga un solo objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Tengo un botón `agregar al carrito` que obtiene el nombre del libro seleccionado de un `ListView`, y se guarda (junto con otros datos) en un `objetoCarrito`, el mismo se guarda en una lista, y la lista en una variable de sesion (todo esto para mostrarlo luego en un `gridView`). El problema es que -*no logro descubrir en qué parte*- se carga un sólo objeto, es decir, siempre me reemplaza el objeto ya guardado con el recién seleccionado. Acá adjunto el código de la función `AgregarAlCarrito`:

**Código:**

```
protected void addCarrito_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string nombre = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    Carrito objCarrito = new Carrito();
    objCarrito.agregarArtCarrito(nombre, objCarrito);
    List<Carrito> productos = new List<Carrito>();
    productos.Add(objCarrito);
    Session["carrito"] = productos;
}
```

La función de `objCarrito.agregarArtCarrito` (que está en una clase carrito) es la siguiente:

```
public void agregarArtCarrito(string nombre, Carrito objCarrito)
{
    Articulos objArt = new Articulos();
    Autores objAutor = new Autores();
    objCarrito.CodArt_ = objArt.buscarCodigo(nombre);
    objCarrito.Precio_ = objArt.buscarPrecio(objCarrito.CodArt_);
    objCarrito.Nombre_ = nombre;
    objCarrito.NombreAutor_ = objAutor.buscarNombre(objArt.buscarCodAutor(objCarrito.CodArt_));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tema es con esta línea:

```
List<Carrito> productos = new List<Carrito>();
```

Siempre estás creando la instancia de los productos y como se crea como una lista vacía, al agregarla a la variable de sesión siempre agregas el último objeto. Sugiero que inicialmente hagas la instancia de la lista, luego, valides si ya existe alguna variable en sesión y si ya existe recuperas la lista agregando el último producto, por ejemplo:

```
List<Carrito> productos = new List<Carrito>();
if(Session["carrito"] != null)
    productos = (List<Carrito>)Session["carrito"];
```

Para que finalmente, tu código quede de la siguiente forma:

```
protected void addCarrito_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string nombre = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    Carrito objCarrito = new Carrito();
    objCarrito.agregarArtCarrito(nombre, objCarrito);
    List<Carrito> productos = new List<Carrito>();
    if(Session["carrito"] != null)
        productos = (List<Carrito>)Session["carrito"];
    productos.Add(objCarrito);
    Session["carrito"] = productos;
}
```

Es decir, primero validas que exista, si existe recuperas los productos existentes y posteriormente agregas el actual.